# How to get source code of a QML method in C++?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml, qt5

I'm writing a serialization of objects to QML, and want to be able to get source code of functions defined in QML object. Suppose I have the following example in QML (`test.qml`):

```
import QtQml 2.2

QtObject {
    function foo() {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

I created a `QObject`: `obj` from that.

**Is there any way (can be hacky) to get the source code of `obj`'s method `foo` without parsing the QML file `obj` was created from?**

It's okay to use `QQmlComponent` `obj` was created from or any other Qt classes, as long as I don't have to parse it myself. Alternatively, how to get the function's source code from the `test.qml` file without writing my own parser? I don't want to assume anything special about `test.qml` (e.g. it can be different than the one above and it doesn't have to be simple enough to use a regexp or other not full-fledged QML parser).

Assuming this works like JavaScript, I tried something like:

```
QQmlExpression expr(engine.rootContext(), obj, "foo.toString()");
QVariant sourceCode = expr.evaluate();
```

However, it doesn't work.

Edit: According to http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.2 the `toString` method of a function object prototype is implementation-defined. In case of QML I get the result:

```
QVariant(QString, "function() { [code] }")
```

Since there doesn't seem to be a way to get the code by JS or C++, I'm not limiting myself to public Qt API anymore.

Comment: You want a source code? or just want to run function?

Comment: I need the source code, not to run the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is impossible to get a source code of a function from an already created QML object. There doesn't seem to be any C++ interface for it and JavaScript doesn't return it using `toSource` method either.

However, it can be retrieved using QML parser. The bad news are that QML parser is a part of Qt private API, so it might not work when using different Qt library builds.

The code to parse QML using Qt 5.3.0 private API is more or less:

`.pro` file:

```
QT += qml qml-private
```

`cpp` file:

```
using namespace QQmlJS::AST;

class LVisitor: public QQmlJS::AST::Visitor {
public:
    LVisitor(QString code): _code(code) {}

    virtual bool visit(FunctionBody *fb) {
        qDebug() << "Visiting FunctionBody" <<
                    printable(fb->firstSourceLocation(), fb->lastSourceLocation());
        return true;
    }

private:
    QStringRef printable(const SourceLocation &start, const SourceLocation &end) {
        return QStringRef(&_code, start.offset, end.offset + end.length - start.offset);
    }

private:
    QString _code;
};

void testQmlParser() {
    QFile file(":/test.qml");
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QString code = file.readAll();
    file.close();

    QQmlJS::Engine engine;
    QQmlJS::Lexer lexer(&engine);

    lexer.setCode(code, 1, true);

    QQmlJS::Parser parser(&engine);

    if (!parser.parse() || !parser.diagnosticMessages().isEmpty()) {
        foreach (const QQmlJS::DiagnosticMessage &m, parser.diagnosticMessages()) {
            qDebug() << "Parse" << (m.isWarning() ? "warning" : "error") << m.message;
        }
    }

    UiProgram *ast = parser.ast();

    LVisitor visitor(code);
    ast->accept(&visitor);
}
```

To get more precise information about the object where the function is defined or just get more information from the AST, implement more methods of `QQmlJS::AST::Visitor`.

Answer (score 0):

I  also didn't find any way to do so. but I found a way around to do it.

reffer [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#accessing-loaded-qml-objects-by-object-name) firts

Now, As you knwo we can access an QML object in C++. will do following to run the function in QML.

```
Item {
    width: 100; height: 100

    Rectangle {
        property bool call:true

        objectName: "rect"
        onCallChanged()
        {
             myFunction();
        }
        function myFunction()
        {
             //your code
        }
    }
}
```

and in C++ you have to do following:

```
QObject *rect = object->findChild<QObject*>("rect");
if (rect)
    rect->setProperty("call", !(rect->property("call").toBool()));
```

here we are using change event of property 'call' to call the myFunction()

Comment: I need the source code, not a method to run the function. Besides, to run the function the snippet I provided would work just fine: `QQmlExpression expr(engine.rootContext(), obj, "foo()");`.